# template match using xpath query

Tags: xslt

my xml has some node with same attribute and i would like to pull them using some xpath hope you can help
so it basically looks like this

```
<myxml>
 <something Type="AT_SAS_6"/>
 <something Type="AT_SAS_50"/>
 <something Type="AT_SAS_200"/>
</myxml>
```

i know that if it was on the name i could do something like

```
<xsl:template match=*[starts-with(name(),  'AT_SAS')]">
```

is there anyway to do the same to attribute value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the XPATH you're looking for is ...

```
myxml/something[starts-with(@Type, "AT_")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Preface attribute names with @ and you can use them in your xpath expressions. Just write a template to match to your root node (myxml), loop through all child "something"'s and then pull the attribute with something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./@Type" />
```